# Issue in Call SOAP service in android

Tags: java, android, web-services, soap

Hello friends i want to integrate SOAP service as below code

```
String METHOD_NAME = "processPayment";
String NAMESPACE = "http://paymentgateway.mcommerce/";
String URL = "http://182.19.20.182:81/mcommerce.webservices/pgService?wsdl";

Element authHeader = new Element();
        authHeader.setNamespace(NAMESPACE);


        Element username = authHeader.createElement(NAMESPACE, "userId");
        username.addChild(Node.TEXT, "aJtlkG0NQTRBaLgVt4YC4A==");
        authHeader.addChild(Node.ELEMENT, username);

        Element password = authHeader.createElement(NAMESPACE, "password");
        password.addChild(Node.TEXT, "7p/MAUl80KP+FdRERRyvlQ==");
        authHeader.addChild(Node.ELEMENT, password);

        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

        request.addProperty("MCODE", "0021225252");
        request.addProperty("TXNDATE", "12052015");
        request.addProperty("TRANSREFNO", "20090824203454");
        request.addProperty("MSISDN", "9879900088");
        request.addProperty("AMT", 100.0);
        request.addProperty("NARRATION", "TEXT");
        request.addProperty("SURCHARGE", 5);
        request.addProperty("FILLER1", "");
        request.addProperty("FILLER2", "");
        request.addProperty("FILLER3", "");
        request.addProperty("FILLER4", "");
        request.addProperty("FILLER5", "");
        request.addProperty("mPIN", "1256");

        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.dotNet = true;
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        envelope.headerOut = new Element[]{authHeader};

        /*envelope.headerOut = new Element[1];
        envelope.headerOut[0] = buildAuthHeader();*/

        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
        try {
            androidHttpTransport.call("", envelope);
            SoapObject response = (SoapObject) envelope.getResponse();
            System.out.print("SOAP RESPONSE " + response);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

When i run above code i get error like this

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot serialize: 100.0 at line
>   androidHttpTransport.call("", envelope);

my SoapAction is empty in my service so i m not mention in code so any idea how can i solve this problem ?

Answer (score 2):

I suppose this line is the culprit:

```
request.addProperty("AMT", 100.0);
```

Observe that 100.0 is not in doublequotes as all the other property values. So change it to

```
request.addProperty("AMT", "100.0");
```

and see if it works.

Comment: i did as you suggests in response string i get following string **anyType{statusCode=101; reason=Authentication failed; }**

Comment: ok, thats a totally different error than the one describing in your question. It is probably an authentication error, are you sure you setup correctly the username/password on your header? As I can see you provide the userId and the password as hashes. I don't think this is correct but I also dont know the auth strategy of your application to help you further.

Comment: elefasGR: Yes this is correct username and password

Comment: elefasGR: first thing tell me i set correct way header parameter posting in my code?

Comment: elefasGR:you can also check in my web api url link [http://182.19.20.182:81/mcommerce.webservices/pgService?wsdl](http://182.19.20.182:81/mcommerce.webservices/pgService?wsdl)

Comment: I cannot access http://182.19.20.182:81/mcommerce.webservices/pgService?wsdl ? It is an IP in your private network I guess!!! Anyway can't you catch the request sent from android in your server-side code and check if it is correct/acceptable? You could try with a program called SoapUI to send a correct request and then adapt it in your android code. Cannot help you any further.